# Android GCM Service Works on One Tablet but not Other

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I've encountered a weird issue in my Android application.
I'm using JQuery Mobile and Cordova 2.4 with the GCM Plugin found here: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

The odd part is that this code works perfectly on my Nexus 7 running 4.2.2 but on the other, albeit much worse, Trio Stealth Pro tablet running 4.0.4, the code does not work at all. I receive no registration ID back from the GCM server when I make the request.

Here is the javascript code making the calls:

```
//cordova's deviceready callback
function onDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

  //setup for GCM Messaging
  userContext.deviceReady = true;
  window.plugins.GCM.register(MY_PROJECT_NUMBER, "GCM_Event", GCM_Success, GCM_Fail);
}

//called from specified attribute in login.html <body onload="onLoad()">
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  document.addEventListener("pause", function () {
    unregisterGCM();
  },
  false);
}
```

I do recieve some errors as my application starts but after I make the registration call but they seem completely unrelated.

```
"call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)"
```

Why would there be this disparate behavior between the two tablets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Trio Stealth Pro does not ship with the Google Play Store, and therefore will not support GCM.

Comment: Wow. Vast oversight on my part. I just assumed that it would have support for the Google Play Store and didn't check.

Comment: @AaronSpringer: Lack of official Play Store support is endemic among low-end devices. There's nothing wrong with that -- heck, the Kindle Fire doesn't have Play Store support and therefore does not support GCM. However, some services, like GCM, only work on Play Store-capable devices. Basically, anything listed on this page will have this limitation: http://developer.android.com/google/index.html